# Ignore index column when loading data to SQLalchemy in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I want to remove the index column as seen on the picture, it already has. I want to remove either of the two. My idea is to use index_ignore = True but not sure where to put it.

[screenshot index column, SQLalchemy in python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFYEy.png)

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

db_file = r'learn-data-analysis-w-python-master/datasets/salesdata.db'

engine = create_engine(r'sqlite:///{}'.format(db_file))
sql = 'SELECT * from scores'
sales_data_df = pd.read_sql(sql, engine)
sales_data_df
```

Comment: Er, just select the columns you're interested in?

Comment: Did the below answer help? If so, feel free to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) (green tick on left) so other users know, or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the absence of data to try my solution with, I can suggest you to try

```
sales_data_df.drop(['index'], axis=1)
```